# “CONFIGURATION” menu is not showing on website panel

Tags: mysql, configuration, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed a website panel on windows server 2012.

I wanted to install MySQL 5.5  on it, and for this case it must to be have a menu with "Configuration" name.
But unfortunately I don't know why, this menu is hide (not appear).

I searched a lot in google and etc, but not found any good solution for it.
In below you can find the picture.
Thanks.

[image: the image of my website panel]

Comment: This question might be better suited to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are logged in as power user "admin". In order to configure your server and applications, you will have to login with "serveradmin" user. Once you login as serveradmin, you will find all configuration options for your server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use default login username 'serveradmin' in websitePanel
and you will get the option of configuration as it seems like you have logged in as admin user.